# Docker Container - How to connect to outside database from a container (not bridge or overlay network)?

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I read about bridge and overlay networks which can be configured in containers but I have the case that my SQL Server is not containerized (it is hosted in Azure on the Azure standard VM) and now  I want to connect from container towards the database? How to enable this network connectivity since overlay and bridge and even host network cannot serve me for these purposes.

Also do I need to set for my container to have the same Virtual Network in Azure so it could access it?

For this scenario I am using Windows Container and using the Azure Container Instance for deployment.

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special; just connect to the database using its Azure host name as normal.  (You would be using "bridge" networking generally.)  Do you have a specific setup that doesn't work?

Comment: you are saying that database and its port will be available immediately without any configuration??? I am really suprised.. why it would be allowed by default I do not understand? Even for standard VMs (no containers) we had to acquire network connection from that VM towards the SQL VM machine on port 1433 and then we had a connection... Please sorry, if I did not state it (I will update it now) my SQL server is being hosted on VM machine and it seems to me I should somehow enable the connection from the container. Thanks

Comment: @DavidMaze I think your comment was not correct, probably I did not define question in proper way. Can you double check your comment? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the Container instance you have the option to create a private / public container instance. choose Private here, create a VNET and give your Database a Private Endpoint in this VNET you can then access the database at this private endpoint address from the container.

You could also do it through a public IP and then whitlist the port to your database (not recommended)

Comment: Hi, sorry but you did not understand the question. I need to access to database which is not in the container from my container (app). Please remove the answer. Thanks

Comment: This solutions is for a extern database

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood that. So they must be on the same VNET? which network driver we should create in this case for Windows l2bridge network dirver correct?
To create a new l2bridge network with subnet 10.244.0.0/24, gateway 10.244.0.1, DNS server 10.244.0.7 and VLAN ID 7.

How I can determine those values - subnet, DNS Server, VLAN and gateway?
Thanks

Comment: Yes the database and your container has to be in the same VNET. You can determine those values when creating a VNET. VLAN are not supported in Azure.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-faq#can-i-bring-my-vlans-to-azure-using-vnets)  more about setting up VNET (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/)

Comment: I already have VNET configured for my VM database so I am not creating new one.
But I am not sure how and where to find the exact values for gateway value, subnet value and dns server value (because in Azure I did not configured anything manually for it). And if I understood you correctly I should exclude this VLANID value from the command line?
And all those settings can be set within the Docker file as well , correct? I mean regarding the network setup.Since that is the more preferred way for us if this can be achieved.
I will open a new question for this in a few minutes.... Thanks

Comment: I marked this as answer, but please if you can assist me on this question since I am not sure how to determine all those values which should be set for my ACI:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65790006/docker-network-l2bridge-how-to-determine-values-for-subnet-gateway-dns-se